# iPhone Auto hide - non modal message

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to show a window with no buttons after every game is finished, to inform the user about the number of points he has earned after the game.
I want it to look like the GameCenter's welcome back window. Transparent, non modal, with no buttons.
What is the best way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make a view called scoreView or something like that, set the transparency/alpha to the desired value, put all your score labels in, and then add that to the game's view. Then when hiding/showing, set the view's hidden property. EX:

```
- (void)scoreScreenTimerClicked {
    scoreView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you XenElement,
I was actually looking for an easy way (something lik action sheet).
But finally decided to do create a custom view. I also use animations to roll the view in and out of the screen area.